# LIbreoffice Impress Change back into Slide edit mode

Tags: libreoffice

Over LibreOffice I am stuck into the following screen:
[image: My Presentation]

But I need to edit something on this slide that will presented on it. Do you fellaz knwo how to do that. I mean I want to chackge back where I can edit the presentation itself and not the notes of it.

I went to the screen shown in screenshot by pressing `Alt` and typing into text box `Σημειώσεις`.

Comment: Might this page help? https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Shortcut_Keys_for_Impress

Answer (score 0):

Select Preview->Normal over the top menu:
[image: Normal Preview Screenshot]